# Mondrian virtual cube not show members

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I have a virtual dimension. Results are right when I query cube, but when I query trhough virtual cube, members are not showed.

Queries:

```
--From cube:

SELECT
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[MyMeasure]})} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({{[MyVirtualDim Usage 0.New Hierarchy 0].[All MyVirtualDim Usage 0.New Hierarchy 0s]}, {[MyVirtualDim Usage 0.New Hierarchy 0].[New Level 0].Members}, {[MyVirtualDim Usage 0.New Hierarchy 0].[curs].Members}})} ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]

--From virtual cube:

SELECT
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({[Measures].[MyMeasure]})} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY {Hierarchize({{[MyVirtualDim.New Hierarchy 0].[All MyVirtualDim.New Hierarchy 0s]}, {[MyVirtualDim.New Hierarchy 0].[New Level 0].Members}, {[MyVirtualDim.New Hierarchy 0].[curs].Members}})} ON ROWS
FROM [MyVirtualCube]
```

Results:

```
--from cube (right)

Axis #0:
{}
Axis #1:
{[Measures].[MyMeasure]}
Axis #2:
{[MyVirtualDim Usage 0.New Hierarchy 0].[All MyVirtualDim Usage 0.New Hierarchy 0s]}
{[MyVirtualDim Usage 0.New Hierarchy 0].[1]}
{[MyVirtualDim Usage 0.New Hierarchy 0].[1].[1]}
{[MyVirtualDim Usage 0.New Hierarchy 0].[1].[2]}
Row #0: 5
Row #1: 5
Row #2: 3
Row #3: 2

--from virtual cube (bad)

Axis #0:
{}
Axis #1:
{[Measures].[MyMeasure]}
Axis #2:
{[MyVirtualDim.New Hierarchy 0].[All MyVirtualDim.New Hierarchy 0s]}
Row #0: 5
```

Here schema definition:

```
<Schema name="New Schema1">

    <Dimension  visible="true" name="MyVirtualDim">
      <Hierarchy name="New Hierarchy 0" visible="true" hasAll="true">
        <Table name="dim2" schema="public" alias="">
        </Table>
        <Level name="New Level 0" visible="true" table="dim2" column="id_nivell" nameColumn="id_nivell" type="Integer" internalType="int" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" caption="nivell" captionColumn="nom_nivell">
          <Property name="nivell" column="nom_nivell" type="String" description="nivell">
          </Property>
        </Level>
        <Level name="curs" visible="true" table="dim2" column="id_curs" nameColumn="id_curs" type="Integer" internalType="int" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" captionColumn="nom_curs">
          <Property name="curs" column="nom_curs" type="String" description="curs">
          </Property>
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>

  <Cube name="MyCube" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="facts" schema="public">
    </Table>
    <DimensionUsage source="MyVirtualDim" name="MyVirtualDim Usage 0" visible="true" foreignKey="fk_dim2" >
    </DimensionUsage>
    <Measure name="MyMeasure" column="id" datatype="Integer" aggregator="count" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>

  <VirtualCube enabled="true" name="MyVirtualCube" visible="true">

    <CubeUsages>
      <CubeUsage cubeName="MyCube" >
      </CubeUsage>
    </CubeUsages>

    <VirtualCubeDimension visible="true" name="MyVirtualDim">
    </VirtualCubeDimension>

    <VirtualCubeMeasure cubeName="MyCube" name="[Measures].[MyMeasure]" visible="true">
    </VirtualCubeMeasure>

  </VirtualCube>
</Schema>
```

Somebody can see where the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved,

Virtual dimensions and virtual cubes runs as expected. To solve my issue it is enough to change dimension name:

```
 <Cube name="MyCube" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="facts" schema="public">
    </Table>
    <DimensionUsage source="MyVirtualDim" name="MyVirtualDim Usage 0" <--here!
```

Should be named: `MyVirtualDim` instead `MyVirtualDim Usage 0` because is the name of the dimension in the cube.